# Four-square Conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, sums-of-squares

Lagrange's four-square theorem states that every nonnegative integer
can be written as the sum of four squares. My following conjecture is much stronger than this classical theorem.

**Four-square Conjecture.** Each integer $n>1$ can be written as 
$$x^2+y^2+(2^a3^b)^2+(2^c5^d)^2$$
with $x,y,a,b,c,d$ nonnegative integers.

I have verified this for all $n=2,\ldots,5\times10^8$ (cf. http://oeis.org/A308734). For example,
$$11= 0^2 + 1^2+ (2^03^1)^2 + (2^05^0)^2=0^2+3^2+(2^03^0)^2 + (2^05^0)^2.$$

It seems that none of the known proofs of Lagrange's four-square theorem could be adapted to yield a proof of the conjecture.

**QUESTION.** Is the Four-square Conjecture true? Can one find a counterexample?

Comment: @tomerg how exactly do you propose to do that? If the conjecture were that every even integer$>2$ is a sum of two prime numbers, how would density be useful?

Comment: Is there some conceptual basis for this conjecture?

Comment: You may look at my related questions mentioned on the right-hand side of this page.

Comment: This is an absurd question given the difficulty of understanding ternary quadratic forms.  Of course one can make all sorts of probabilistically justified conjectures like this, but is there a second sentence that anyone can write on problems like this?

Comment: I don't like too rude comments. It seems to me that there is no other person who realized such a conjecture before.

Comment: Note that $16265031$ cannot be written as $x^2+y^2+(2^a3^b)^2 + (2^c3^d)^2$ with $x,y,a,b,c,d$ nonnegative integers.

Comment: One could write a computer program to generate a dizzying list of conjectures that "no other person realized" before. That alone doesn't make any such conjecture valuable or interesting. (Also, did you just defend your conjecture and then disprove it in consecutive comments?)

Comment: I don't think so. If one has never imagined or realized a new type of problems, he would not be able to write corresponding programs. The first original one is important, once the first one appears others might follow to find more.

Comment: @Greg, the conjecture involves $2^c5^d$, the comment doesn't, so unless there's a typo there's no contradiction.

Comment: I have extended the verification of the Four-square Conjecture to $10^9$ with no counterexample found.

Comment: Today, Giovanni Resta reported on OEIS that he had verified the Four-square Conjecture for all $n=2,3,\ldots,10^{10}$.